# relation on column with different name from model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two tables as **events** and **organisations**. In an organization may have multiple events .In the past i was not familier with laravel so i created Events and Organizations Model. I added foreign key in the migration of events table as

```
$table->bigInteger('organization_id')->unsigned()->default(null)->nullable();
```

Now i can't change organization_id to organizations_id because there are lots of line code. Also i did in Organizations.php model as

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Events::class);
}
```

Also in Events.php model as

```
public function organization() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Organizations::class);
}
```

So when i want to save event in organizations as

```
$organizations->events()->save($event); // $event is an object to be save in organization
```

then it gives an exception that

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'events.organizations_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `events` where `events`.`organizations_id` = 3 and `events`.`organizations_id` is not null)

I can understand that i have to keep Organizations model to Organization, but it is not possible for now. So any other way to map it with organization_id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can, just provider the column name that represent the relation as second argument in your relation:

in Events model:

```
public function organization() 
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Organizations::class,'organization_id');
}
```

for more details, see Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).